# Conditionally set checkbox state based on variable in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isChecked = this.isChecked.bind(this);
  }

  isChecked(ex){
    return this.props.defaults && $.inArray(ex, this.props.defaults);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="example">
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
          var checked = this.isChecked({item.type});

          <span key={item.type}>
            <input type="checkbox" {checked ? 'checked' : ''} name="example" value={item.type} id={item.type} />
            <label htmlFor={item.type}>{item.display}</label>
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above example, I have passed a list of items to the component `this.props.items` and a list of defaults `this.props.defaults`. For each item, if the item is in the list of defaults, I would like its state to be `checked`. Leaving the overall design the same, how can I do that? (Note: I realize I can redesign the application to avoid the issue of declaring the variable inside the map. That is not the question).

The above code doesn't work (obviously), I am just trying to give everyone an idea of what I'm attempting here. The error given if you run this is something like "unexpected token" at the spot where "var" is declared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the `render` method had some syntax errors, this should work:

```
render() {

  return (
    <div className="example">
      {this.props.items.map((item) => {
        var checked = this.isChecked(item.type);

        return (
          <span key={item.type}>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked ? 'checked' : ''} name="example" value={item.type} id={item.type} />
            <label htmlFor={item.type}>{item.display}</label>
          </span>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

That main mistakes were declaring the function in map, you have to wrap item in parens and surround the function with brackets instead of parens. If a fat arrow function has only one statement, you don't need to specify `return`. But in this case you added the `var checked` line, so you now have to explicitly make the other line a `return` statement. There was also an issue with how you set `checked` in the input. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The reason I set checked the way I did was because in HTML the mere presence of the word 'checked' indicates the box should be checked; the value does not matter. Is that incorrect? But I do think I'd have to use the dangerouslySetInnerHtml method to do things the way I was attempting. By the way, the advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Oh I see why you were trying to just spit out checked, but yeah in this case that's not valid jsx syntax. React handles that optimization for you, you won't see "checked=true" in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. There were a couple other minor mistakes, for example, the key={item.type} should be key={item.type + checked} so that reactJS will re-render the list if the default checked items change. Obviously, you had no way of knowing that since it's specific to my implementation. Thanks so much for your help!